# Trailing slash removal opening full directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to remove the trailing slash of all urls. Whatever htaccess script lines I try, it always redirects to what seems the full server directory.
`example.com/XYZ/` weirdly redirects to `example.com/customers/b/7/3/example.com/httpd.www/XYZ` – Not found.

Basically, I'm not using any subdirectories but getting data out of a database according to what's the last string after the last slash. So the "Not found" error is ok, because there actually isn't an existing folder.

I'm new to htaccess, so I was just trying out whatever lines I found.

*Rewrite so that anything opens index.php and not a folder (which works fine without trailing slash, Engine is on):*

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?$1
```

*I failed by using this to remove the slash:*

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

So basically what I'm trying to do is:

- Open any url as index.php. For example `example.com/XY` doesn't actually redirect but show/open index.php (I think I achieved that with above two lines)
- While doing so, I'm trying to also remove the trailing slash from e.g. `example.com/XY/`, so `example.com/XY` and `example.com/XY/` both show/open index.php

Thanks for your wisdom!

Comment: General tip, use `example.com`. `xxx.com` is an actual valid porn site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ /index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```